Como atribuir cores dinamicamente a background(textField) no Jasper Studio?

Como atribuir uma cor ao campo que por exemplo tiver o valor EX: tipo == catraca, e se caso ele tenha outro valor esse mesmo campo assuma outra cor ou fique com a cor patrão?

É possível fazer isso através dos Styles, é só criar um style e atribuir a ele um efeito condicional, aonde você deve pegar a variável em questão $F{var} e fazer uma comparação $F{var} == 1 depois disso é só você alterar do estilo condicinal que vc criou na sessão de appearance caso vc queira alterar a cor do fundo vc mexer no backcolor e caso vc queira alterar as letra vc alterar o forecolor, vale lembra de desmarcar no condicional estilo que vc tem que desmarcar a caixinha de transparência, segue abaixo imagens demostrando como fica.
Demonstração de como fica o estilo condicional criado

Demonstração de como deve ser atribuída a cor

Demonstração de como ficou a comparação


Quem tiver duvida pode perguntar, agora dar negativo ....
